# How to open an website inside the react-native app(Android and iOS)

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I need to open the website inside my react-native app. Needs to work for both iOS and Android

Comment: Do you need it to be opened inside on of your screens or it could be opened inside external webbrowser?

Comment: you can use react-native -webview

Comment: @KirillKunst I need to open inside in my screens I need to design the header and footer section of that screen

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WebView` component: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html.

Something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native';
class MyWebViewComponent extends Component {
  render() {
     return (
      <WebView
         source={{uri: 'https://google.com'}}
         style={{marginTop: 10}}
      />
    );
  }
}
```